# How do Isolate a string of text in Excel that begins with a space and ends with a comma?

Tags: string, excel

I have a column of cells with addresses like below:

- 34470 Yucaipa Boulevard Yucaipa, CA 992399
- 15787 Main Street Hesperia, CA 92345
- 15109 Bear Valley Road Victorville, CA 92345

I want to pull out the City, State Zip; I'm trying to write a formula to accomplish this but I am having trouble.

Basically I'm looking for a way to find a coma, *read the string from right to left*, and stop at the first space; seems simple enough....

So in the examples above I'm looking to pull out the following strings

- Yucaipa, CA 992399
- Hesperia, CA 92345
- Victorville, CA 92345

Comment: searching for space to left of comma would fail on San Francisco, San Mateo, etc

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that downfall. Luckily my data only has cities that don't have spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1))," ","@",LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1))," ",""))))+1,LEN(A1))
```

This returns:

```
Yucaipa, CA 992399
Hesperia, CA 92345
Victorville, CA 92345
```

From your test data.

If by any chance you have `@` symbol in your texts, you can try this instead:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1))," ",CHAR(1),LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1))," ",""))))+1,LEN(A1))
```

---

### Explanation

`=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1))` gives `34470 Yucaipa Boulevard Yucaipa,`. Let's call this bit 'Text'.

`=SUBSTITUTE(Text," ","@",LEN(Text)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Text," ","")))`. This bit is to replace the last instance of space by `@`. The 4th parameter of `SUBSTITUTE` gives the instance of the space to be replaced, and `LEN(Text)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Text," ",""))` gives the number of spaces in the text. You get `34470 Yucaipa Boulevard@Yucaipa,` as result for this part

Then, do a `MID` on this to get the position of the `@` till the end.

Comment: Wow - That's amazing. I like how you find the instance of spaces by essentially removing them all and then taking that number of characters subtracted from the original string of text. Pure Genius. I'd love to learn these type of advanced string manipulation techniques; any advice as to where I can learn more or tools inside of excel that would help me learn?

Comment: @user2749122 I learned then by seeing the answers to questions a bit similar to yours on StackOverflow and combining each bit I learned each time :)

Comment: @user2749122 Oops, I was testing that in a F3, thanks for spotting that :)

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2010, you can use the Text-to-Columns feature on the Data ribbon.

This explains it in more detail at [addictivetips](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/excel-2010-split-column-data-into-two-parse-cells/)

After you've split the data into columns, add a new column that concatenates the city, state and zip together.  Something like =CONCATENATE(D2, " ", E2, " ", F2).

Comment: The reason the Text-to-Columns feature won't work is because it parses the data too much, basically in the above 2 examples I only want to return "Yucaipa, CA 992399" from the first string and "Hesperia, CA 92345" from the second string

Comment: After you've split the data into columns, then concatenate the one you want back together with something like =CONCATENATE(D2, " ", E2, " ", F2)

Comment: This would work only if all the street addresses were uniform. The only thing that is constant is that there is a comma between the city and state and I want to use this is as a "flag". I have 300+ rows I need to edit. If a address is 123 Main Street and another is 5467 Vine Road Lane I'll end up with too many columns and not all rows will have the city, state zip in the same columns.

Comment: Your desired solution also relies on city names that are a single word with no spaces.  Not clear that there is an great 'formula' here, you might be better off with user defined functions.  There is no reverse MID function that I'm aware of.

Comment: Luckily all City names are single words.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
=LEFT(
    RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(",",A1)-1),
    SEARCH(" ",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(",",A1)-1))-1)
```

The only problem with this kind of search is that your data needs to be ultra-clean. In your sample I had to skip the space immediately after the comma, but if your data doesn't always have the space it won't work properly.

Based on your comments, try this:

```
=LEFT(
    RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1)),
    SEARCH(",",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1)))-1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, but I think I'm doing a poor job explaining my issue. What I need it to do is 1) find the comma 2)move to the left up to the first space than return all characters to the right after that space. My comment to the 2nd answer explains the desired outcome

Comment: I think you are on the right track though. Would you be able to explain how/why this works the way it does? I think given that information I could try and solve my problem

Comment: @user2749122 - I've provided a solution for you. Please experiment with the four functions I've used to see how they work. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this has not been mentioned:

=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),297))